# Where to put files to access them publicly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, root

I need to place a Google archive in my root to verify my domain.
Why when I put it in /public , I can't access it from mydomain.com/thearchive ?

How do I need to place files in order to access them in from my root in a rails app?

I'm hosting it at Heroku.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your config/environments/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets=true
```

Comment: That made the trick, but suddently other parts of my website **** up.
Is there another way?

Comment: What broke after that? Heroku even has a plugin for that - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline !

Answer (score 0):

You can try add an action in one of your controller. For example, run

```
rails generate controller home google_verify
```

And then copy the verification code into your `/app/views/home/google_verify.html.erb`

And then modify your routes to make it work. For example, in your `/config/routes.rb`

```
get '/google_verify' => 'home#google_verify'
```